# How to remotely find out a linux hostname without the use of DNS?

Tags: linux, dns, domain, hostname, wins-server

If I want to find out how the hostname of a remote linux machine on my LAN is, how can I achieve this given I don't have access via SSH etc.?

Probably depends if linux is part of a WINS domain I suppose.

Comment: What information do you have?

Comment: Only the IP address of the machine.

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to specify the term *hostname* more closely. If you are looking for the name as it is known to the DNS server that you don't want to use - there is no way of knowing except for actually asking that DNS server.

If you are simply guessing, [nmap](http://nmap.org/) can be of good use. For example, if there is a smbd running on that server, the output of `nmap -A` might look like this:

```
Host script results:
| smb-security-mode:
|   Account that was used for smb scripts: guest
|   User-level authentication
|   SMB Security: Challenge/response passwords supported
|_  Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)
|_smbv2-enabled: Server doesn't support SMBv2 protocol
|_nbstat: NetBIOS name: FOOBAR, NetBIOS user: <unknown>, NetBIOS MAC: <unknown>
| smb-os-discovery:
|   OS: Unix (Samba 3.5.6)
|   Computer name: foobar
|   Domain name: lan
|   FQDN: foobar.lan
|   NetBIOS computer name:
|_  System time: 2013-03-14 17:02:27 UTC+1
```

Other services might give hints about the name of the machine as well.

Comment: That would be a solution, of course it depends on a listening smbd deamon.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of a DNS server, this might work:

```
traceroute 1.2.3.4
```

Alternatively, if the server in question is exporting Samba shares, you could do this:

```
smbclient -L 1.2.3.4
```

This depends on whether you have a working DNS server set up on your LAN that has the necessary information. If it does, this command should do what you need:

```
nslookup 1.2.3.4
```

or

```
host 1.2.3.4
```

Finally, another useful command is

```
arp -a
```

Comment: There's no DNS server..

Comment: @Ian, yes I finally read the title and not only the body of your question and figured that out. Sorry. Anyway, the `traceroute` and `smbclient` options might work.

Comment: traceroute also uses dns to resolve names

Answer (score 2):

Fingerd (and xinetd) are easy to set up and require no maintenance.

```
$ finger root@10.3.0.3
[10.3.0.3:79]

Welcome to Linux version 3.5.7-12-tryggve at tryggve.lan !
(...)
```